# C++ Memory mapped file data prefetching

Tags: c++, mmap, prefetch

I'm dealing with very large memory mapped files (200+ GB) which can not be loaded fully into memory, and are accessed randomly. The mapped files are stored on a solid state drive array, but I still find that accessing the needed parts one at a time is very slow unless the same search has been done previously, and the pages used have already been read into memory.

Adding multiple threads to read the variables in the mmap simultaneously improves the speed dramatically, and I was unable to reach an upper bound to the improvement in my testing, but having more than 1000 threads causes openmp to throw resource unavailable errors.

I have also tried madvise to advise the kernel of the specific parts which will be needed (MADV_WILLNEED) but the kernel does not seem to act on the advise quick enough to make a difference.

I'm looking for a way to simultaneously prefetch the parts of the data needed immediately prior to them actually being used. What would be the least resource intensive way to read a variable (or the memory page sized piece of the mapped file containing it) forcing it into memory without blocking on the read.

If blocking can not be avoided, a way to run a much larger number of very light weight threads to do the reading would also work.

Comment: I'm confused by what you want. It sounds like madvise does what you want, you just need to call it earlier. There will be some delay between asking for a block of data from the disk and actually getting it. Regardless of the fact that it's an SSD, the whole I/O system is going to have some delay (probably non-negligible).

Comment: I would have thought so too. The batches to be read are entirely random, and frequently contain 150k entries to be processed. Each entry is approximately 2KB, and they are processed immediately after being identified, so unfortunately I'm unable to use madvise any earlier. The way that running multiple threads improves the overall mmap access time makes it seem like the kernel is not acting on the advise, or is taking its time potentially due to the large number of madvise calls.

Comment: The best solution might be to use platform-specific functionality.  Can you specify your platform?

Comment: @ridley3 Did you get to solve this at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question. Your only solution besides threading is to loop through however many accesses you can doing `madvise` for each. Then after some x number of `madvise`s (say 10,000) you come back and access the memory. It should be noted however that the O/S does **NOT** guarantee that the I/O will be done in the order that madvise is called. Therefore, the O/S might process the first madvise, then jump to the end of the madvises, or the one with lowest address, basically whatever it pleases. There simply is no way to considerably speed up I/O to the extent it sounds like you want.

Example:

```
for(i=0; i < accesses + 10000; ++i)
{
    madvise(access[i].addr, access[i].length, MADV_WILLNEED);
    if(i >= 10000)
    {
        // Access location access[i-10000].addr
    }
}
```

You should however ask yourself if memory mapping this file is really what you want to do if you're using random access. It would seem that asynchronous I/O would make better sense.

Comment: That kind of madvise loop is exactly what I tried doing, but it did not seem to have any significant effect.

Comment: Well, then the operating system is probably not prioritizing the I/O based on the order of madvise calls. Your only choice other than threads would be to use asynchronous I/O.